# What is the best way to toggle python prints?

Tags: python, printing

I'm running Python 2.4 in a game engine and I want to be able to turn off all prints if needed. For example I'd like to have the prints on for a debug build, and then turned off for a release build.
It's also imperative that it's as transparent as possible.

My solution to this in the C code of the engine is having the `printf` function inside a `vararg` macro, and defining that to do nothing in a release build.

This is my current solution:

```
DebugPrints = True
def PRINT (*args):
    global DebugPrints
    if DebugPrints:
        string = ""
        for arg in args:
            string += " " + str(arg)
        print string
```

It makes it easy to toggle print outs, but there is possibly a better way to format the string. My main issue is that this is actually adding a lot more function calls to the program.

I'm wondering if there is anything you can do to how the print keyword works?

Comment: instead of the for loop, you can use `print " ".join(args)`

Comment: oops, that should have been print " ".join(map(str, args))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

yes, you can assign `sys.stdout` to whatever you want. Create a little class with a `write` method that does nothing:

```
class DevNull(object):
    def write(self, arg):
        pass

import sys    
sys.stdout = DevNull()
print "this goes to nirvana!"
```

With the same technique you can also have your prints logged to a file by setting `sys.stdout` to an opened file object.

Comment: Don't forget to 'backup' sys.stdout if you wish to re-enable it later.  _stdout = sys.stdout; sys.stdout = DevNull()

Comment: With modules like "logging", this method seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: 'ridiculous' is a bit over the top but i get your point. I should have named the question 'easiest way to toggle prints', maybe?

Answer (score 11):

I know an answer has already been marked as correct, but Python has a debug flag that provides a cleaner solution.  You use it like this:

```
if __debug__:
    print "whoa"
```

If you invoke Python with -O or -OO (as you normally would for a release build), `__debug__` is set to `False`.  What's even better is that `__debug__` is a special case for the interpreter; it will actually strip out that code when it writes the `pyc/pyo` files, making the resulting code smaller/faster.  Note that you can't assign values to `__debug__`, so it's entirely based off those command-line arguments.

Comment: +1: That is useful to know, even if its a bit more effort to implement

Comment: It's kind of a shame the debug flag is on when you simply do python ./thescript.py (instead of using the -d debug flag)

Answer (score 9):

The [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) is the "best" way.. although I quite often just use something simple like..

```
class MyLogger:
    def _displayMessage(self, message, level = None):
        # This can be modified easily
        if level is not None:
            print "[%s] %s" % (level, message
        else:
            print "[default] %s" % (message)

    def debug(self, message):
        self._displayMessage(message, level = "debug")
    def info(self, message):
        self._displayMessage(message, level = "info")

log = MyLogger()
log.info("test")
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use print, but make a console class which handles all printing. Simply make calls to the console and the console can decide whether or not to actually print them. A console class is also useful for things like error and warning messages or redirecting where the output goes.

Comment: Yeah, an existing logging module is worth looking at. Depending on the scope of the project, a small class might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to toggle printing:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> print 'foo'
foo
>>> origstdout = sys.stdout
>>> sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
>>> print 'foo'
>>> sys.stdout = origstdout
>>> print 'foo'
foo
```

However, I recommend you only use `print` for throwaway code. Use `logging` for real apps like the original question describes. It allows for a sliding scale of verbosity, so you can have only the important logging, or more verbose logging of usually less important details.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.debug('foo')
DEBUG:root:foo
```

For example, usage might be to put debugging logs throughout your code. Then to silence them, change your level to a higher level, one of `INFO`, `WARN` or `WARNING`, `ERROR`, or `CRITICAL` or `FATAL`

```
>>> logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logging.debug('foo')
>>>
```

In a script you'll want to just set this in the `basicConfig` like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logging.debug('foo') # this will be silent
```

More sophisticated usage of logging can be found [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

---

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this question on a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487941/efficient-way-of-toggling-on-off-print-statements-in-python/32488016#32488016) but was the question was marked duplicate:

anyhow, here's what I would do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
DebugPrints = 0

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    if DebugPrints:
        return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)

print('foo') # doesn't get printed
DebugPrints = 1
print('bar') # gets printed
```

sadly you can't keep the py2 print syntax `print 'foo'`

Comment: Works nicely. But how does the print function know about `enable_print`, if it's not global and hasn't been passed as an argument?