# Efficient way of toggling on/off print statements in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I have 10 or 15 very useful debugging `print` statements sprinkled throughout my program (in different functions and in `main`).

I won't always want or need the log file though. I have a config file in which I could add a parameter to toggle print statements on or off. But then, I'd have to add a guard check for the value of this parameter above every print statement.

What are some better approaches?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, the answer is to use the logging module, I'd delete this before it gets closed.

Comment: @AaronHall Fair point, thanks. taesu has provided a nice alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function
enable_print = 0

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    if enable_print:
        return __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)

print('foo') # doesn't get printed
enable_print = 1
print('bar') # gets printed
```

sadly you can't keep the py2 print syntax `print 'foo'`

Comment: Nicely done, thanks.

Comment: How does the `print` function know about `enable_print`, if it's not global and hasn't been passed as an argument?

Comment: I don't know at which version the change occurs but as of Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) `__builtins__` is a dictionary. The approach still works by replacing `__builtins__.print` by `__builtins__["print"]`.